# React Router does not refresh the page when clicking on a Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In React, `react-router-dom` does not refresh the page when clicking on a `<Link>` element.

Specifically, when making a link like the below (the `Button` element is just a button with styling, and the code has been simplified):

```
import { Route, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Stats from "./pages/Stats";

<div className="pt-5 pl-24">
  <Button orange>
    <Link to="/stats">Start Taking Stats</Link>
  </Button>
</div>

<Routes>
  <Route path="/stats" element={<Stats />} />
</Routes>
```

Looking at other forums, it says to add an `onClick` to refresh the page like so:

```
<Link to="/stats" onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>
  Start Taking Stats
</Link>
```

However, this does not work, as when the button is clicked, the page refreshes without changing the contents. The address bar changes for a few milliseconds, but then immediately goes back to the original path.

This warning also appears on the home page.

```
No routes matched location "/"
```

[image: Warning]

The `Stats.jsx` file is located at `<project root>/src/pages/Stats.jsx`. Its contents are below.

```
function Stats() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>world</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default Stats;
```

Is there anything to be done in any files, or to install any packages, to get this working?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]. What is the component in the first snippet and where is it rendered? The error is simply saying the app isn't rendering any route for path `"/"`. The app should have that route. Can you share the router and routes?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you have not defined `home` route that is of `/` or may be because you are missing `exact`.
And remove `onClick` method.

Try one of the following:

```
  <Route path="/stats" exact element={<Stats />} />
```

---

```
 <Route path={"/"} exact element={<Home />} />
 <Route path="/stats" element={<Stats />} />
```